# What is this fastener attaching electrical box to concrete wall and how do I remove it?

Tags: concrete, junction-box, fastener

I have a ranch house built in 1985 in Pennsylvania. The foundation is poured concrete. I want to replace one of the electrical boxes in the basement with a 2-gang.

What is the white plastic fastener seen in the photo (there are two). There is a shallow slot across the top of the metal pin in the center, but it doesn't appear to be deep enough to be a screw.

Should I try to unscrew it? Or just pry the box loose?

[image: outletbox]

Comment: If you have a hammer-drill to drill in concrete you’re better off using tap-cons. Much more stout fastener.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I call them "pin anchors" but I think they have a longer actual name like "mushroom head drive anchors". The anchor is set by driving with a hammer, but can be "un-set" by unscrewing the pin because it has a twist thread on it. Just unscrew then pry out.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: p.s. they are not terribly strong in my experience, but maybe they worked ok here because the conduit is also strapped. If you are installing frequently used receptacles you might consider a more robust anchoring strategy.

Comment: yes, I would use 4 for anchoring a electrical outlet, but our australian plugs are about twice the size of american ones, so the two in the picture are probably enough.

Comment: I was able to unscrew the pin. It only came about halfway out because the threads only go halfway down the pin. The inserts pulled out of the wall easily.

Comment: Perfect! As designed, with the pin pulled back, no more outward pressure on the plastic ans it can be removed. I have had them get stuck and had to use a cat's paw to pull them...

Answer (score 3):

It's just a plastic wall plug, sometimes called an expansion anchor or by various brands names. https://www.confast.com/product-1-4-x-2-nylon-nail-it-round-head/

Sometimes you can successfully rotate and remove the pin, but a flat claw hammer will normally take them out pretty quickly.

If installing a new box in the old holes you can use a more permanent replacement version that are often called "lead anchors", even though they aren't made from lead any longer.  https://www.homedepot.com/p/Red-Head-1-4-in-x-1-in-Hammer-Set-Nail-Drive-Concrete-Anchors-25-Pack-35200/100129334

When installing these anchors often times the hole in the electrical boxes is a bit to small for the anchor to slide through, you can usually slide a good quality nut driver or deep socket over the pin and gently persuade the anchor through the hole with a hammer.

Comment: you won't get claw hammer into that electrical box. but if you chisel the flanges off  then locking pliers might do the trick.

Comment: You just claw the whole box off the wall.

Comment: The anchors in second link are made of zinc, not lead.

Answer (score 2):

They are called nylon nail-its.  Drill 3/16" or 1/4" hole, push them in then hammer them down till snug.  Just take a narrow-tipped flat screw driver and back them out.  No big deal.